# Unable to understand how rounding is working for decimal digits (Java)

Tags: java

While working on one implementation, i saw difference in amount being shown at 2 places.While doing some more debugging i found this information.

I have 2 decimal values and both getting rounded to 2 decimal places.

```
double value =1091.225;
double value1 =48.125;

System.out.println((double)Math.round(value * 100) / 100);      
System.out.println((double)Math.round(value1 * 100) / 100);


BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(value);
price = price.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP);
double val= ((long) (value < 0 ? value * 100 - 0.5 : value * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0;


BigDecimal price1 = new BigDecimal(value1);
price1 = price1.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP);
double val1= ((long) (value1 < 0 ? value1 * 100 - 0.5 : value1 * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0;

System.out.println(val);
System.out.println(val1);
```

These are results

```
1091.22
48.13
1091.22
48.13
```

However if i change values to

```
double value =1091.255;
double value1 =48.125;
```

Results are different

```
1091.26
48.13
1091.26
48.13
```

Can anyone please help me to understand as why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the way floating point numbers are stored in memory. The value `1091.225`, and `1091.255d`, don't have exact binary representation. Try printing their value using the below statements:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1091.225d));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1091.255d));
```

Output will be:

```
1091.22499999999990905052982270717620849609375
1091.2550000000001091393642127513885498046875
```

It's clear that the first one will be rounded to `.22`, and 2nd one to `.26`.

Comment: I don't think you meant that for two identical values there would be different output?

Comment: @eis. I don't understand your comment. Those are two different numbers I've printed.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because decimal values are not stored as precise values, and you are discarting decimal part by casting to long.
Try this to better understand:

```
System.out.println(value * 100 + 0.5);
System.out.println((long)(value * 100 + 0.5));
```

This prints

```
109122.99999999999
109122
```

So divided by 100.0 it is 1091.22

But for other values it prints

```
109126.00000000001
109126
```

So divided by 100.0 it is  1091.26

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round()` is the issue here.

> public static int round(float a) Returns the closest int to the
>   argument. **The result is rounded to an integer by adding 1/2,** taking
>   the floor of the result, and casting the result to type int. In other
>   words, the result is equal to the value of the expression:
>   **(int)Math.floor(a + 0.5f)**

Hope this helps.

Also, note that the precision for decimal point values are not accurate, since they cannot be represented perfectly in binary form.

[This should help.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202843/solutions-for-floating-point-rounding-errors)